# Why isnt my application_helper.rb helping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im doing Michael Hartl's excellent tutorial series on ruby on rails here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

and im having an issue in 4.1.1, where he refactors the title of the pages to rely on application)helper.rb to set the tag. Ive done exactly what he said in the book, and for some reason it never seems to kick in. Each title of my page has the name given in the @title variable in pages_controller.rb or if i omit it i will get some sort of controller error displayed where the title should be. My code is at github:

https://github.com/ekimia/mTwitter

Thanks for helping a Ruby on Rails newbie out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb change `<%=@title%>` to `<%=title%>`.

If you prepend the "@" then it will try to access the variable `@title` which would be set in the controller. Without the "@" it will call the `title` method (or helper rather), which you defined in app/helpers/application_helper.rb